# Matlab:2nd order polynomial, force it to go through origin, R^2

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have some x-y data points. I would like to add a quadratic polynomial regression to it, and force the regression curve to go through the origin (0/0).

Additionally, is there a function to quickly calculate R^2 for the resulting curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question, so you'll get a broad answer.

Have a look at the **Curve fitting tool** [**`cftool`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/cftool.html) and you'll see it will enable you to define constraints like "fit should go trough origin":

- Fit options -> upper & lower bounds for `p3` **= 0**

and it displays the desired `R^2`.

Now have a look at the [**`fit`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) function and use your previous settings to feed that function and you'll get similar results.

Comment: The tool is called cftool rather than cft, but it provides exactly what I was looking for. I only knew about the basic fitting tool, but this is much better!

Comment: @traindriver I actually meant this, just a typo ;)